# External USB 3.0 disk became much slower, why?

Tags: performance, external-hard-drive, usb-3

Two months ago I got a newly formatted Lenovo P50 with Windows 10 Pro and I wished to test its USB 3.0 ports.
I was using Crystal DiskMark 8.0.1. The tested disk was standard magnetic Transcend disk.
The results were very nice and I saved them for the future.

Lately I have bought two USB 3.0 extensions cables and I wanted to check them. The results (for large files) were 40% slower then these in the past and I have already prepared to accuse the cables, but then I remove the cable(s) and got an almost the same results as with cable(s)!!!

So, the conclusion is that cable was not the problem.

My question is: **why** the speed of my disk deteriorated?
I tried the following things to fix this (i.e. to reach previous speed), but without results:

1. Disable antivirus and other background processes
2. Return disk caching (Device Manager / Disk Drives, Policies / Better performance)

Here are the images, the first before two months and the second now. The only difference is that disk is slightly more filled:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How much more full is the disk now compared to then? The outer tracks of a disk tend to be faster and so you may well have a faster disk when nearly empty compared to nearly full.

Comment: You can see on images: first time it was 77%, and the second was 84%. It doesn't seem that such small difference in space can impact speed so much. However, I 'll empty disk and try speed then.

Comment: It's been a while since I needed to use Crystal so I wasn't sure about what the percentages meant. That said a program called [HD Tach](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6714-hdtach.html) can show you the speed at various points of the disk and will look something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGEkw.png. a 30MB/s drop does seem quite extreme though. I'd expect to see that kind of speed difference between the start and end of a drive, but not that much in the middle.